# Adobe XD: Updating triggers of component's states

Tags: adobe-xd, prototyping

I have a quick question about components and states. I'd like to change the interaction between states of a symbol across all my artboards. It has 50 instances. Basically, it has to update from a button with the text "Add to cart" to a checkmark ✅. Easy right?

Well, I managed to get various states on my symbol and added an interaction but didn't manage to get the same interaction across all the instances.

Do you have any idea on how to get the same interaction across all components?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to reflect your changes in all the places, you have to make the changes in your **Master component**. have added my example below.

Select the **Assets Tab**. Right click on the component, in which you have to make changes. Select the **Edit Master component**.

[image: Right click on the component]

Canvas will show the Master component highlighted in green. Add all your states.

Then switch to **Prototype** tab and add all interactions for your states and run. You can see all of your instances will have same behavior.

I hope this solves your problem. Happy Designing.

Comment: Hi and thank you for your answer ! Finally managed to update my components but didn't update my question. I pushed the change of the master component and it worked :) Didn't know that ! Thanks a lot.